# Django CMS error: modules are not found despite being installed

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I am trying to install beta version 3 of Django CMS.

Although all modules and dependencies and everything is there, whenever I try to `syncdb`, I get errors like this:

```
ImportError cms.plugins.file: No module named plugins.file
```

If I uncomment it, the next one gives the error:

```
ImportError cms.plugins.flash: No module named plugins.flash
```

Only when I uncomment them all can I install.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the core plugins have been removed from the cms.

http://docs.django-cms.org/en/develop/upgrade/3.0.html#plugins-removed